# Apache mod_rewrite: get rewritten directories as array and maintain the query string

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get via PHP some variables in `$_REQUEST` from a rewritten URL.

The rewritten URLs will look like this:

```
http://localhost/base_folder/dir1/dir2/dir3?lang=en&type=1
```

or just

```
http://localhost/base_folder/dir1?lang=en&type=1
```

What I would like to have in my `$_REQUEST` variable is something like this:

```
Array(
    [req] = Array(
        [0] = dir1,
        [1] = dir2,
        [2] = dir3,
        [etc...] = etc...
    ),
    [lang] = en,
    [type] = 1,
)
```

I have placed my file .htaccess in the directory `/localhost/bade_dir/` but I was not able to create a decent rewrite rule to get what I want. For the moment my .htaccess file looks like what is below and I want to be able to get those parameters always from my file `/localhost/bade_dir/index.php`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?req[]=$1 [L]
```

I know that the `/?$` in my regex is wrong as well as the `$1` but I don't know a lot of apache/regex.

Is anybody able to help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule with `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /bade_dir/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?req[]=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you but that will not give me the result I want in case the URL is the following:

http://localhost/base_folder/dir1/dir2/dir3?lang=en&type=1

With that Rule the query string is maintained but if I launch that URL I get a 404 NOT Found Error so my `req` array is not populated as I wanted.

Comment: Okay thank you, that's more than enough even though the `req` array still contains only one key and the directories are contained in the first result. I will explode the values via PHP. Thank you